# TCP socket connection to lokal broker

Tags: sockets, tcp, connection, hivemq

Im trying to connect to a small server(broker), HiveMQ, with a TCP socket connection. When I ping the server via cmd I get the message:

`TCP   0.0.0.0:1883         0.0.0.0:0        LISTENING`

The connection code in C is like this:

`addr.sin_family = SL_AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = sl_Htons(1883);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = sl_Htonl("0.0.0.0");`

And I get this error:

`Error [-111] at line [926] in function [ConnectionToHiveMq]`

which indicates an error whith my socket connection:

`rc = sl_Connect(mysock, (SlSockAddr_t *) &addr, sizeof(addr));`

Can someone help me with this? I have tried many different portnumbers and IP:s but still doesn't work. Itis working if I connect to an application client on the web, where I can subscribe messages from this code. But when Itry with my lokal (broker) server, it dosent...

Answer (score 0):

The `0.0.0.0:1883` in the [`netstat(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/netstat.8.html) output `TCP 0.0.0.0:1883 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING` just means that the server is listening on port 1883 on *all available interfaces* on that box. You still need a valid IP address to connect to it though (something like `192.168.0.1`), which would be the address of one of those interfaces (see [`ifconfig(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ifconfig.8.html)), and is `127.0.0.1` for the *loopback* interface, if you are on the same machine.

Also, your code line `addr.sin_addr.s_addr = sl_Htonl("0.0.0.0");` is completely wrong. You need to convert the string representation of the IP address to its integer form with, e.g., [`inet_pton(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html).

Comment: Ok, thanks alot Nikolai N Fetissov!, that explain it very good! 

What is meant by "loopback interface"? Is it the interface I sent data(subscribe) from?

Comment: Loopback is a *virtual* network interface that always means *this computer*. It would be the interface named `lo` in the `ifconfig` output if you are on a Linux box.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's the same if you run it on a windows machine?

Comment: Yes, interface name will be different, but the IP `127.0.0.1` is standard across the board. On Windows you want to use `ipconfig` command instead of Unix `ifconfig`.

Comment: I have one more question that I need some answer to. Im, as I ment earlier, using a broker (a small server that just passing the data thrue subscribe and publish messages). Do I have to connect to the broker with this TCP code. Or to the client, that I wish to subscribe to?

Comment: That I have no idea about - you will have to look into HiveMQ documentation. Also note that you can **accept** useful answers here :)

Comment: Ok, but anyway. Thanks alot for your help, that clarify it very much!